# How to force an IOException in jimfs

Tags: unit-testing, jimfs

I have file related code to test where I would like to test my error handling for an existing file that I cannot read.

```
class SomeClass {
    //...
    public void load(Path path) {
       if (!Files.isRegularFile(path)) {
           return null;
       }
       //...
       try {
           // ...
       catch (IOException e) {
           // cleanup
       }
    }
}
```

I am using [jimfs](https://github.com/google/jimfs) to isolate the tests from the real file system.

So how would I create a file on jimfs that is not readable?

I have already tried assigning posix permissions and a different user to the path through `Files.setAttribute` on the desired path, both of which seem to have been ignored when attempting to read or write to the path.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there isn't currently any support for actual permission/access checking for files in Jimfs. It's something that I think would be good to have, but I haven't worked out the details: see [this issue](https://github.com/google/jimfs/issues/11) and [this somewhat related issue](https://github.com/google/jimfs/issues/15).

Comment: Is there any other way to induce an `IOExcetpion` from jimfs, so that the error handling code could be tested?